# How to select next matching element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works:

```
<a href="#/link1">link1</a>
<a href="#/link2">link2</a>
<a href="#/link3">link3</a>

$("a[href*='#/link1'").next('a[href*="#"]').click();
```

but this does not:

```
<a href="#/link1">link1</a><br>
<a href="#/link2">link2</a><br>
<a href="#/link3">link3</a><br>

$("a[href*='#/link1'").next('a[href*="#"]').click();
```

The above tests the "< br >" tag, not the next matching link.

How would I go about making it work in both situations. I want to select the next matching element, not the next element if it matches. Maybe .next() isn't the correct method?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The second example should not select anything at all. Read the [documentation of `next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

> **Get the immediately following sibling of each element** in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

You have to use `nextAll` to get *all* siblings and filter them accordingly:

```
$("a[href*='#/link1']").nextAll('a[href*="#"]:first').click();
```

**Reference**: [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

Comment: I think the OP is aware of the shortfalls of `.next()`, be sure to read the *entire* question ;)

Comment: @Nick Craver: I swear it was written *The above **selects** the `<br>` tag* ... maybe it was just wishful thinking... I'm tired ;)

Comment: What exactly happens if you don't use ":first"? Would it click all the links?

Comment: @Dave: Yes. At least every link that matches.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) to get the next sibling that matches, rather than the next sibling *if* it matches, like this:

```
$("a[href*='#/link1'").nextAll('a[href*="#"]:first').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own simple jQuery plugin called `nextMatching`:

```
$.fn.nextMatching = function(selector) {
    return this.nextAll(selector).first();
};
```

And use it like this: given the following markup...

```
<li id="startingElement">one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
<li>four</li>
<li id="targetElement">five</li>
<li>six</li>
```

...and starting with the element one, you can select element five like this:

```
$('#startingElement').nextMatching('#targetElement');
```