# Navigation not working because of br tag

Tags: jquery

I have the below code where the cursor should move when pressing the up and down arrows but because `br` tag  is present the navigation does not happen as expected. Is it possible to have such a requirement when there are intermediate elements and we do not want to highlight the intermediate elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            //init
            $('.focused').focus();

            // actual code
            $(document).keydown(function(e) {

                if (e.keyCode == 38) { // left
                    if ($('.focused').prev('.focusable').length) 
                        $('.focused').removeClass('focused').prev('.focusable').focus().addClass('focused');
                }
                if (e.keyCode == 40) { // right
                    if ($('.focused').next('.focusable').length) 
                        $('.focused').removeClass('focused').next('.focusable').focus().addClass('focused');
                }
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .focused {
                border: 1px solid red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>Comments just added to format the question

    <body>
        Comments just added to format the question 
        <a href='jqwja' class="focusable">jajaj</a>
        Comments just added to format the question<br>
        <a href='jjaasd' class="focusable focused">jajasdaaj</a><br> 
        <a href='jjqwea' class="focusable">jajaacasj</a><br>
        <input value='iddqd' name="DoomII" class="focusable" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661714/how-to-select-next-matching-element ?

Comment: I would just not use break tags, rather margin or padding.

Comment: `prev()` and `next()` are for immediate siblings and the `<br>` is a sibling. There are other traversal methods in api you can use

Comment: You can try something like `.nextAll('.focusable').first()`

Comment: Something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9Luaqkr/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Try reformatting the navigation to something like below, and apply the style to .focus/.focusable a

```
 <div class="focusable">
   Comments just added to format the question 
   <a href='jqwja' >jajaj</a>
</div>
  <div class="focusable">
   Comments just added to format the question 
   <a href='jqwja' >jajaj</a>
</div>
 <div class="focusable">
       Comments just added to format the question 
       <a href='jqwja' >jajaj</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: That assumes that OP has control over the output. Suppose this was user generated in WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: @charlietfl Well I am assuming since since they are supplying us with their JS, this is not a WYSIWYG editor.